# Create union of tuples with empty tuple without type never appearing in forEach

Tags: typescript, tuples, union, typescript-never

I effectively would like a typed array that will only ever have a set number of items — in the example below, 0, 3, or 8.

However, the type of the contents when calling forEach or similar ends up being `never` due to the `[]`.

```js
type O = {prop:number}
type T = []|[O,O,O]|[O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O]

let t:T = []


t.forEach(v=>{
    v.prop // <- error, v is type never
})
```

A reason for the approach is to allow TS to be more aggressive with array index access checking, e.g.

```js
t[0].prop += 1 // ! t[0] is type O|undefined
```

This may be a bit silly but I stepped on my own foot because T is [] very infrequently and TS array access is permissive. Given I know it's always either empty, length x, or length y, I figured it'd be an easy safety to just spec it.

Comment: Why not just type it as `O[]`?

Comment: Ah, clarified in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

It seems like the workaround is not needed at all. The reason for the error is that TypeScript outsmarts us here. The compiler can see that you assigned an empty array to `t` and *ignores* the explicit type you gave `t`. There is *hidden* type information associated with `t` which makes its type just `[]` and not `T`.

We can stop this behavior with a type assertion.

```
let t: T = [] as T

t.forEach(v=>{
    v.prop // number
})
```

And the error is gone.

The assertion is only needed in this case because you assigned a literal value to `t`. If the value of `t` is truly unknown because it is generated at runtime or passed via argument, this is not needed.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeYBOB7MAuAdgVwFsAjCVAXwFgAoUSKAFQSgG0BdAH2ZgBoeYOuvIX2G9W1agBsIwKMCwMmbKAEMAzgwk0AdADN0qAKIqAxgAsAFADd4APiTUoTqFe1pMUAPSeo+YqWoyAEogA)

---

One possible workaround could be to *not* use the `[]` type to represent an empty array. Instead, use an `O[]` and intersect it with `{ length: 0 }`.

```
type T = (O[] & { length: 0 }) | [O,O,O] | [O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O]
```

Assigning arrays of various lengths still works as before.

```
// valid
let t: T = []
t = [{prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}]
t = [{prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}, {prop: 0}]

// invalid
t = [{ prop: 0 }]
```

And the error in the `forEach` is gone.

```
t.forEach(v => {
    v.prop // number
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeYBOB7MAuAdgVwFsAjCVAXwFgAoUSKAFQSgAoYBtAXSgDJkoAbCDgDmwABZYoABihkAlFAA+UNjAA06mF2WqNezfo0dq1APSmoANwCG-AJYATaoOBRgkxok7VXXlBmxpMjVkNExJKWDQgIiyYxomNn9woJDkwMi0sIyo9NismNTolMzinIKSuJMqcyg7HBt7JwS-KGyI2XifADoAM3RUAFFrAGMxZksEAD5kaih5q27sqFqAHgBaKFIMVBDJuwBnN3BoHAhLUmp5IA)

---

A cleaner approach would probably just to check if `t` is empty before using it for the `.forEach`.

```
let t: T = [] as T

t.length !== 0 && t.forEach(v=>{
    v.prop // number
})
```

TypeScript is smart enough the exclude the `[]` type from the type `t` by checking the `length`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeYBOB7MAuAdgVwFsAjCVAXwFgAoUSKAFQSgG0BdAH2ZgBoeYOuvIX2G9W1agBsIwKMCwMmbKAEMAzgwk0AdNJwBzYAAsoAQniIADFABkNudoBm6VAFEVAYyMAKAG7wAPiRqKFCoX200TCgAehioAB4AWihSDFRucKgASw1aaBwIX1JqMgBKIA)

Comment: The note about implicit type information with `[]` is fascinating and the casting useful indeed. I've been encountering the `never` issue _intermittently_ in a larger codebase (TS literally flags it, then stops then starts again then stops, with various unrelated code changes) I wonder if the default `[]` value somewhere is causing some weirdness...

Comment: Using the type assertion allows you to also drop the implicit annotation.